# How do I add validation for stuff like passwords or IC where the first character has to be a certain letter and characters?

Tags: python, spyder

I would like to check that the ic is correct before moving to read the csv file.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
nric = input("Enter your NRIC number: ")

def checklength(): #defining the checking of length of nric characters
   return len(nric) == 9

def checkfirstcharac():
    firstcharac = ["S", "T"]
    return nric[0] == firstcharac

while not checklength() and checkfirstcharac():
    print("Your nric input is not valid, please make the following corrections:")
    if not checklength():
        print("NRIC must be 9 characters long.")
    if not checkfirstcharac():
        print("NRIC must start with either an S or T.")
    nric = input("Enter your NRIC number: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

first you aren't checking for S T being the first letter correctly, you're checking that the first letter = a list ["S", "T"] rather than checking if the first letter is IN the list so you'll want this instead:

```
def checkfirstcharac():
    firstcharac = ["S", "T"]
    return nric[0] in firstcharac
```

And your while loop should look like this:

```
valid = False
while valid == False:
    nric = input("Enter your NRIC number: ")
    if not checklength() or not checkfirstcharac():
        print("Your nric input is not valid, please make the following corrections:")
        if not checklength():
            print("NRIC must be 9 characters long.")
        if not checkfirstcharac():
            print("NRIC must start with either an S or T.")
    else:
        valid = True # this will break the loop
```